# Why are most of the Europa League games played at 20.05 GMT?

Tags: football, uefa

I mean, instead of the usual 19.45 GMT for the UEFA Champions League games? Is this due to sponsorship reasons or are there no reason at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Game playing time determined at [Europa League regulations](http://www.uefa.com/MultimediaFiles/Download/Regulations/competitions/Regulations/01/80/06/31/1800631_DOWNLOAD.pdf).

It is under the following section:

> VII Fixtures, Match Dates, Venues and Kick-off Times
>
> **Kick-off time of the qualifying matches and play-offs.**
>
> 12.02 The home club fixes the kick-off time for all matches of the qualifying phase and the play-offs.
>
> **Kick-off time until the round of 16.**
>
> 12.03 As a rule, matches in the UEFA Europa League kick off either at 19.00 hours CET or 21.05 hours CET. On the basis of the draw, the UEFA administration will fix the kick-off times. Exceptions to this rule
>   may be made by the UEFA administration.
>
> 12.04 In principle, the fixtures within a group on the last matchday must be played simultaneously.
>
> **Kick-off time from the quarter-finals.**
>
> 12.05 In principle, quarter-finals and semi-finals kick off at 21.05 CET. Exceptions to this rule may be set by the UEFA administration.
>
> 12.06 Inprinciple, the final kicks off at 20.45CET.